# Different “mount” processes in Arch Linux install

Tags: arch-linux, mount

I have seen some videos about "How to install Arch ...". My question is about "mount" process, what is the difference between:

**This**

```
mount /dev/sdax /mnt
mkdir /mnt/boot
mkdir /mnt/boot/EFI
mount /dev/sdax' /mnt/boot/EFI
```

**And This**

```
mount /dev/sdax /mnt
mkdir /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sdax' /mnt/boot
```

Because I try both and they both work, so what is the difference?

Comment: Please don't follow any videos. Instead, follow the [official Arch installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide), and follow it _to the letter_. Do not change _anything_. I first installed Arch after being a Linux user for almost 20 years, so not exactly a newbie, and I still had problems whenever I changed anything from the guide. When I followed the guide, everything was perfect. But don't follow random youtube videos. Arch has among the best documentation out there, *use it*!

Comment: Are you sure there is a stray single quote? That command will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The four-line sequence is specific to [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) booting with [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitions, not suited to systems with [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) [Legacy](https://fossbytes.com/uefi-bios-gpt-mbr-whats-difference/) formatted partitions

The three-line sequence is more generic.